# Create a function that takes a string (some sentence) and split it into list of tuples (word, length word)

Tags: string, list, haskell, fold

> Create a function that takes a string and splits it into list of
> tuples of type `(word, length word)`. It needs to be done using
> `foldr` through one pass of the list, without using `length` and/or
> `(++)`.
>
> For example
>
> ```
> > splitSen "    Asdf  qw   zx     mn      "
> [("Asdf",4),("qw",2),("zx",2),("mn",2)]
> ```

My implementation looks like that

```
splitSen :: String -> [(String,Int)]
splitSen cs = foldr func [] cs where
  func ' ' ((c1,n1) : ps) = ps
  func c ((c1,n1) : ps) = (c:c1,1+n1):ps
```

And I get an error

> *** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function func

But can not figure out what pattern I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's turn warnings on! This can be done with the `-Wall` flag.

```
$ ghci -Wall
> :{
| splitSen :: String -> [(String,Int)]
| splitSen cs = foldr func [] cs where
|   func ' ' ((c1,n1) : ps) = ps
|   func c ((c1,n1) : ps) = (c:c1,1+n1):ps
| :}

<interactive>:6:3: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘func’:
        Patterns not matched:
            p [] where p is not one of {' '}
            ' ' []

<interactive>:6:14: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: ‘c1’

<interactive>:6:17: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: ‘n1’
```

Above, the warning tells that the empty list case `[]` is not handled in `func`.

Comment: that is true, but also I now see that my whole function is incorrect.

Comment: @BohdanChornopolskyi I haven't thought much about how to solve it, but chances are that you need to use a move complex "accumulator" than just the final result list. Maybe you need a pair containing 1) your list and 2) a boolean indicating whether the next non-space starts its own word, so to track spaces in some way. After the `foldr`, you can throw away the boolean with `fst`. This technique is the same as that used in your previous question: build a tuple with more information for the fold, and discard half of it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ever will have something similar here what I managed to make

```
splitSen = fst . foldr func ([], True) where
  func ' ' ([], _) = ([], True)
  func c ([],bool) | bool = ([([c],1)], False)
  func ' ' (((word, len):rest), bool) = (((word, len):rest), True)
  func c (y@((word, len):rest), bool) | bool = (([c],1):y, False) 
                    | otherwise = (((c:word, 1+len):rest), False)
```

Looks really bad but works...